# unable to call a wwebmethod from remote validator Form validations

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webmethod, formvalidation-plugin

Whenever, I am calling webmethod from remote validator, it's throwing below warning.

[Synchronization XMLHTTPrequest...(Click here to see warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65PNK.png)

Because of this warning, i am not able to call webmethod.
Here is my code for calling webmethod.

```
txtUsername: {
                      verbose: false,
                      async: true,  
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: '<%=Resources.LocalizedText.UserNameRequired%>'
                        },
                        stringLength: {
                            min: 6,
                            max: 30,
                            message: '<%=Resources.LocalizedText.UserNameAtleastSixChars%>.'
                        },
                        regexp: {
                            regexp: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+$/,
                            message: '<%=Resources.LocalizedText.InvalidCharactersOnlylettersNumAndUnderscores%>'
                        },
                        remote:{

                            remote: {
                                message: 'The username is not available',
                                url: '/BackOfficeOperations/HMS/SimpleHMS.aspx/checkUsername',
                                data: {
                                    type: 'txtUsername'
                                },
                                type: 'POST'
                            }
                        }
```

This is Html code:

```
 <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-3 control-label">
                                <%=Resources.LocalizedText.UserName%>:</label>
                                <div class="col-md-7" style="left: 1px; top: 0px">
                                   <%-- <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" runat="server" class="form-control" OnTextChanged="checkUsername();"  ></asp:TextBox>--%>
                                <input  type="text"  class="form-control" name="txtUsername" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

This is webmethod

```
  [WebMethod]
    public static CompleteResponse checkUsername(string txtUsername)
    {
        var tsvc = new TenantService();
        if (tsvc.UserNameExists(txtUsername))
        {

            return new CompleteResponse { message = "", success = true };
        }
        else
        {

            return new CompleteResponse { message = "", success = false };
        }
    }
```

Comment: try using `ajax` calls

Comment: @manish can you suggest me how to do ajax call?

Comment: I am not able to write there @manish

Comment: just a second i forgot to give write access

Comment: I got your point. But i have used Form validations and on textchange i want to call this webmethod

Comment: oh, you need atleast 20 reputations to talk in a room, that's so sad

Comment: yup. I have joined now

Comment: `$('#textboxId').change(function() { $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "YorFileName.aspx/WebMethodName",
        data: '{name: "' + $("#<%=txtUserName.ClientID%>")[0].value + '" }',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response){
   console.log(response);
  },
        failure: function(response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    });ing } );`

Comment: does that make sense ?

Comment: ok let me try this one.